# Seleccionar el registro de mayor valor dentro de un JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Tengo procedimiento con un `SELECT` con varios **JOINS** y, en uno de ellos, necesito extraer sólo un resultado (el de la fecha más reciente) cuando pueden darse varios resultados realmente. En principio, las fechas no van a ser exactas nunca ya que se almacena en formato `DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss` y el campo fecha es de tipo `DATE`.

A modo de ejemplo, tendríamos alguna consulta como la siguiente:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
FROM tabla3 t3
LEFT JOIN Tabla1 t1 ON t1.key = t3.key
LEFT JOIN Tabla2 t2 ON t2.key = t3.key
LEFT JOIN Vista_VW vw ON vw.key = t2.key 
     -- AND vw.FECHA // (en este JOIN quiero escoger sólo el registro de fecha mayor)
```

El valor del campo `FECHA` no me interesa en el `SELECT`, tan sólo lo necesito usar como filtro del `JOIN`. La fecha se encuentra en la vista `VW`

¿Cómo hacer el `JOIN` en la consulta que devuelva el registro de `FECHA` más reciente?

Como resultado espero obtener una pila de datos bastante grande (por los otros `JOINS`) pero de este último `JOIN` sólo me interesa sacar un registro y no termino de ver claro cómo formular la consulta `SELECT`.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. En preguntas de este tipo, es una buena idea que incluyas un ejemplo de los datos de las tablas que quieres incluir en el join y un ejemplo de la salida que esperas. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate: la salida que espero obtener es, como digo en la pregunta, una pila de datos que, en _UNO_ de los **JOIN** no me incluya más de _UN sólo resultado_

Comment: ya edité la pregunta para que se entendiera mejor, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función ventana `ROW_NUMBER()` se adapta muy bien a lo que pides. Puedes usar la claúsula `ORDER BY` de la función para numerar los registros en orden de fecha. Luego puedes filtrar por los registros a los que se les asignó el rango `1` para limitar los resultados a los registros con la fecha más reciente:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
FROM tabla3 t3
LEFT JOIN Tabla1 t1 ON t1.key = t3.key
LEFT JOIN Tabla2 t2 ON t2.key = t3.key
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT vw.*, -- opcionalmente, puedes modificar esta parte si no necesitas todas las columnas de la vista
         row_number() over (
             partition by vw.key
             order by vw.fecha desc) as rn
    FROM Vista_VW vw
) vw ON vw.key = t2.key AND vw.rn = 1
```

Comment: La verdad a 1ª vista y, seguramente por mi desconocimiento de la función, me parece una solución un tanto complicada y enrevesada para lo que quiero. Pensaba que existiría otra forma más *simple* de hacerlo. En cuanto tenga algo de tiempo probaré tu código a ver si me aclaro. Gracias de todos modos

Comment: Te entiendo. Y no digo que sea la única forma de hacerlo. Pero las alternativas que conozco son aún más complicadas con más subqueries y menos eficientes. Que yo sepa, el uso de `row_number()` es la forma más sencilla de hacer lo que pides.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar ejecutando primero una consulta para obtener la fecha maxima y luego otra para la comparación, solo te quedaría adaptarlo a tus necesidades

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla c2    
WHERE fechaemision = (
                      SELECT max(fechaemision)
                      FROM tabla
                      )
```

Comment: Hola w33haa. Puede que esta solución funcione si no hay joins. Pero con joins, no es tan simple. Adicionalmente, no está claro si el campo fecha realmente es de tipo `date` o no. Si no lo es, usar `max(fechaemision)` no necesariamente devolverá la fecha mas reciente.

Comment: @w33haa  en este caso no puedo separarlo en 2 consultas, y además tampoco es la forma que realmente busco, ya que se trata de un procedimiento llamado por un handler al servidor. Gracias igualmente